# Homomorphism from algebra $(\mathbf{R}^3 \times \mathbf{R}^2, +, \cdot)$ to $(\mathbf{R}^3, +, \cdot)$ where $f((a,b,c), (x,y))=(c,b,a)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

On the sets $\mathbf{R}^3$ and $\mathbf{R}^2$ are defined addition and multiplication with scalar from $\mathbf{Q}$ by coordinates. The problem is to prove that $f:\mathbf{R}^3 \times \mathbf{R}^2 \to \mathbf{R}^3$, where $f((a,b,c), (x,y))=(c,b,a)$ is homomorphism from algebra $(\mathbf{R}^3 \times \mathbf{R}^2, +, \cdot)$ to algebra $(\mathbf{R}^3, +, \cdot)$.

I know that for operation (+) must be $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$, so in my case it will be:
$$f(((a_1, b_1, c_1),(x_1, y_1)) +((a_2, b_2, c_2),(x_2, y_2)))=f((a_1+a_2, b_1+b_2, c_1+c_2),(x_1+x_2, y_1+y_2))=(c_1+c_2, b_1+b_2, a_1+a_2)=(c_1, b_1, a_1) + (c_2, b_2, a_2) = f((a_1, b_1, c_1),(x_1, y_1))+f((a_2, b_2, c_2), (x_2, y_2))$$

But, I have a problem with operation ($\cdot$), and my question is how can I multiply elements written in coordinates? what is for example $(a,b,c)\cdot(x,y,t)$?

Does for homomorphism, maybe, when function is written by coordinates, necessary to check $f(\alpha a) = \alpha f(a)$?

For homomorphism on algebras it must satisfy both operations. Can we say that $f$ is homomorphism just for addition and not for multiplication?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify what kind of "algebra" are you talking about. Notice that $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is a field, whereas no power of $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be given field structure, for $n\neq0,1,2$. That is assuming you mean the real numbers by that $R$ you wrote. If it is a general ring, the usual product in coordinates should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you Davide! I edited my post. It seems that R is set of real numbers, that was problem from my exam. You say if it is general ring, then I can use usual product in coordinates, how can I find product in coordinates, for example (1,2,3) \cdot (4,5,6)? Is this scalar product where I will get real number as solution?$